# Gem mysql connection error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am getting error while trying to use gem 'mysql' to connect to DB

```
/home/sajeesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': libperconaserverclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/sajeesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@global/gems/mysql-2.9.1/lib/mysql/mysql_api.so (LoadError)
    from /home/sajeesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/sajeesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@global/gems/mysql-2.9.1/lib/mysql.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /home/sajeesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@global/gems/mysql-2.9.1/lib/mysql.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/sajeesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `require'
    from /home/sajeesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/sajeesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
    from ./mysql.rb:7:in `<main>'
-bash-4.1$ 

-bash-4.1$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.4p265 (2014-10-27 revision 48166) [x86_64-linux]
-bash-4.1$ gem list | grep mysql
mysql (2.9.1)
-bash-4.1$
```

Is there any possible workaround to this; I have uninstalled and installed mysql gem multiple times and also tried higher versions of ruby too; nothing seems to be working. Please help me with the solution.

Comment: What version is your mysql instance?

Comment: Its, Server version: 5.6.34-79.1

Comment: I just saw, but are you using `gem 'mysql'` or `gem 'mysql2'`? Because if your using `mysql`, then change it to `mysql2` and bundle, then try.

Comment: Yeah i was using 'mysql' gem

Answer (score 0):

make sure you use `mysql2` gem then bundle and make sure that your database config files have the right configuration for connection.

Comment: Thanks for the input; I removed all the ruby versions from the node and installed the latest bundle and it worked.